# Mongoose schema virtual attribute always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was trying to use mongoose schema virtual functions to implement flags, But I could not make them work The mongoose database is hosted on `mongodb altas`. I have tried deleting the whole collection and staring again.

Here is a simplified example:

Let us say I have a basic User Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String
}, {toObject: {virtuals: true, getters: true}})

UserSchema.virtual('status').get(() => {
   return this.name
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = {
    User,
    UserSchema
}
```

In `app.js` I have the following:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const {User} = require("./models/User")
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

User.findById("600ae8001931ad49eae40c03", (err, doc) => {
    console.log(doc.status)
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I made sure the id exists, but the result is always `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

> Do not declare methods using ES6 arrow functions (=>). Arrow functions
> explicitly prevent binding this, so your method will not have access
> to the document and the above examples will not work

so you can not use arrow function in `get`, do like this :

```
UserSchema.virtual('status').get(function() {
  return this.name
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To future users people that looking for the answer, beside this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850012/12743243) - if it's not solve the problem and still get undefined -

the problem maybe because you didn't `select` the attribute that used in the virtual middleware

#### Our Schema

```js
const monthSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    numOfDays: Number,
  },
  { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
);
```

If you use `numOfDays` in virtual middleware to calculate the weeks like this:

```js
MonthSchema.virtual('numOfWeeks').get(function() {
  return this.numOfDays / 7
})
```

If you want to get`numOfWeeks` you must be sure that `numOfDays` are selected

```js
const user = await User.find().select('name'); // this.numOfWeeks will be undefined

const user = await User.find().select('-numOfDays'); // this.numOfWeeks will be undefined

const user = await User.find().select('name numOfDays'); // this.numOfWeeks will be not undefined
```

I spent whole day to figure this, may be this will help someone

Comment: I'm using Mongoose 6.8.1 and it's worth mentioning that using a fat arrow function inside `get()` was also a contributing factor.

Comment: I had a `select` in my query and your comment helped me solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how you are declaring your function being passed to `get`. The way you are doing it is changing the `this` reference.

```js
UserSchema.virtual('status').get(function() {
  return this.name
})
```

The above would maintain it